# How do I get Crumbs to use the dynamic title from a view?

Tags: 7, views, breadcrumbs

I have a view set up with a:
Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)

[image]

When I preview I see the title...

[image]

However in Crumbs when I go to the DEBUG tab for the view url:

[image]

How do I get Crumbs to recognise this Title from the view??

Comment: Is the views page path explicitly "stock/%"? And did you flush caches after configuring the view? (especially menu rebuild) I just tried it myself and it seems to work.

Comment: Perhaps you also need to play with the validation criteria.

Comment: Nope, the validation criteria do not seem to be relevant.